# What form of adress is 「ボクちゃん」?

Tags: word-choice, usage

In [a video game I'm playing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irozuki_Tincle_no_Koi_no_Balloon_Trip), the main character, who is a middle-aged man, and his child-like young friend meet a farmer, who seems to address the younger of the two as 「ボクちゃん」.

An example:

> オレは ピーター。この はたけの オーナーだ。オヤジと ボクちゃんは どうして ここに?

What exactly does ボクちゃん mean here? What does his choice of words tell us about his opinion of the other two men?

Is the word possibly related to [坊ちゃん](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E5%9D%8A%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93), or does the "manservant" meaning of [僕](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E5%83%95) come into play here?

Comment: See #2-2 http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/203330/m0u/ (P.S. jisho.orgにも、『2. You (used addressing young children).「ぼくだいじょうぶ？」といわれました。I was asked, "You OK, kid?"』って書いてあるやん！)

Comment: この回答は参考になるでしょうか・・・?　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/8126/1016

Comment: Expanding on Choko's comment, kids (boys in particular) use the term ぼく to refer to themselves.  Japanese is more flexible about how personal pronouns are used, so in the context of your example, ピーター is using the word ボク to refer to the young boy ("child-like young friend", presumably male), and definitely *not* as a first-person way of referring to himself.

Comment: @Choko That's certainly similar to my own question. The answer is applicable, too.